# DrawerLayout in AndroidX is Missing?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, androidx

I use `DrawerLayout` and Hamburger menu in my App. I migrated my App to `Androidx`. Everything it seems right but `DrawerLayout`. It doesn't know `DrawerLayout` Class.

What I have to do?

Comment: make sure you are using it from androidX and not support library version.

Comment: post the relevant java or xml code.

Comment: did you tried import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AndroidX has [its implementation of `DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout?hl=en).

Add `implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"` to your module's dependencies (you can check [Google's Maven repository catalog](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) to confirm the available versions).

Comment: Just to correct a little typo, is "implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0'" (notice the . after drawerlayout)

Answer (score 17):

you sould replace drawerlayout in xml with below line

```
androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"` in your build.gradle file, then in the layout file you want to use drawer layout, change `<androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout` 
tag to `<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`.

Comment: What is the difference between those two? I have both available, but the `core` drawer does not allow `FrameLayout` as a child element, while the other one allows it (like the `support` drawer did).

Answer (score 1):

1. First step:

   `implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"`
2. add on top of your layout add:

   `<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>`
3. Must end by closing tag:

   `</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>`